# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, express, parent-child

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to fetch posts (called screams) from the database and render them on a home page. I'm getting the error that Objects are not valid as React children, but when I console.log my (res.data), I get what looks like an array of objects. Could someone please help with this, I've been trying to figure it out for days!

Here is my error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/pages/home.js:17
  14 | .get('/screams')
  15 | .then((res) => {
  16 |     console.log(res.data)
> 17 |     this.setState({
     | ^  18 |         screams: res.data
  19 |     })
  20 | })
```

Here is my Home component that fetches the screams:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Scream from '../components/Scream'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

export class home extends Component {
    state = {
        screams: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('/screams')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    screams: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }

    render() {
        let recentScreamsMarkup = this.state.screams ? (
            this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream key={scream.screamId} scream={scream}/>)
        ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
        )
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                    <p>Content...</p>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile...</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default home
```

Here is my Screams component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//MUI stuff
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


const styles = {
    card: {
        display: 'flex',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    image: {
        minWidth: 200,
    },
    content: {
        padding: 25,
        objectFit: 'cover'
    }
}

export class Scream extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, scream : { body, createdAt, userImage, userHandle, screamId, likeCount, commentCount } } = this.props
        return (
           <Card className={classes.card}>
               <CardMedia 
               image={userImage}
               title="Profile image" className={classes.image}/>
               <CardContent className={classes.content}>
                    <Typography 
                    variant="h5" 
                    component={Link} 
                    to={`/users/${userHandle}`}
                    color='blue'>
                        {userHandle}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{createdAt}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
               </CardContent>
           </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Scream);
```

Here is the output of console.log(res.data):

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {screamId: "hdPO8XHJapHFIwT3bTqG", body: "posting a new scream this one is so sick", userHandle: "mitch", createdAt: "2021-02-18T22:26:37.093Z", commentCount: 0, …}
1: {screamId: "lRhyZ588AMfka3KS6pc7", body: "test for token", userHandle: "user", createdAt: "2021-02-17T16:40:36.236Z"}
2: {screamId: "X6Attw1xXLMXnxkUm0aV", body: "New scream7", userHandle: "Jane", createdAt: "2021-02-16T05:11:23.963Z"}
3: {screamId: "wELQNKd8a7yiMLGJmFu1", body: "new scream 6", userHandle: "johnny", createdAt: {…}}
4: {screamId: "Fr5lypvRzrn43oFWJMtr", body: "New scream 2", userHandle: "New", createdAt: {…}, commentCount: "3", …}
5: {screamId: "ro5p1vDVyR8yYp7SEnBD", body: "New scream", userHandle: "New", createdAt: {…}}
6: {screamId: "n0auykwJooMxCuDSSWTH", body: "test 4", userHandle: "user", createdAt: {…}}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
concat: ƒ concat()
constructor: ƒ Array()
copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()
entries: ƒ entries()
every: ƒ every()
fill: ƒ fill()
filter: ƒ filter()
find: ƒ find()
findIndex: ƒ findIndex()
flat: ƒ flat()
flatMap: ƒ flatMap()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
includes: ƒ includes()
indexOf: ƒ indexOf()
join: ƒ join()
keys: ƒ keys()
lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()
length: 0
map: ƒ map()
pop: ƒ pop()
push: ƒ push()
reduce: ƒ reduce()
reduceRight: ƒ reduceRight()
reverse: ƒ reverse()
shift: ƒ shift()
slice: ƒ slice()
some: ƒ some()
sort: ƒ sort()
splice: ƒ splice()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
unshift: ƒ unshift()
values: ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true, findIndex: true, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: `createdAt` appears to be an objects in some elements. Can you expand element 6 for example and see what it looks like?

Comment: Wow, thanks for catching that! I started inputting createdAt data in timestamp format, but later switched to strings and forgot to delete the old data. I think that was stopping me from fetching the data. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in the initial state make it empty array instead of null.

```
 state = {
        screams: []
    };
```

And make sure you are getting an array from the API request...
Try mapping threw a test array first.

```
     state = {
          screams: [
              {first obj},
              {second obj},
            ]
            };
```

Comment: This did it! Setting state to an empty array instead of null fixed the error! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome my friend! can you please vote for useful answer for me then :)